# Favorite Questions and answers from second quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

[The post is now live](https://thesffblog.com/2019/07/highlights-from-2019-2nd-quarter/?preview=true).

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2019 through June 30th 2019.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/04/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

> Sometimes I really hate Reddit all the time.

Comment: You really like the word "Also".

Comment: @TheAsh Also, your face!

Comment: I get paid by the ‘also’.

Answer (score 3):

[Reflected-sound-of-underground-spirits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/210720/what-term-is-being-referred-to-with-reflected-sound-of-underground-spirits) A puzzle that brings back old memories, but one I can't remember if I solved or had the answer handed to me.